# Is it possible to run python code in a web browser?

Tags: python, html, pandas

My code below is a pandas dataframe, I've tried transcypt and flask to view this code in my browser, but have had errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['cap', 'title', 'price']
df = pd.read_csv('asdawhiskey.csv', names=columns)

items = df[df['cap'] == '70cl']

print(items.to_html())
```

Comment: You can use `Django` framework, but if you want to just `print()` something to browser, it would be hard to do. **Edit**: you can ask new question and add errors that you get when trying Flask.

Comment: "I've tried transcypt and flask to view this code in my browser, but have had errors" -> What errors were you getting? Something like this seems fairly easy to set up in `Flask`

Comment: Firstly thank you for your response. The code creates a html table format in my terminal but I want to be able to physically see the table in a browser, will Django framework achieve this?

Comment: Could you just save the output to file (using > redirection) and open that file?

Comment: Have you tried [brython](https://brython.info/)?

Comment: I have seen an example from https://sarahleejane.github.io/learning/python/2015/08/09/simple-tables-in-webapps-using-flask-and-pandas-with-python.html on how to use Flask and this would be great to replicate for my table but I had a could not import FLASK APP error. 

I have not yet tried brython would this work with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Streamlit. https://streamlit.io
You don't have to write a single line of html

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

columns = ['cap', 'title', 'price']
df = pd.read_csv('asdawhiskey.csv', names=columns)

items = df[df['cap'] == '70cl']

st.write(items)
```

Then run `streamlit run example.py`

Comment: Hey Naveen, Please correct the function name for writing

Comment: Fixed it, sorry for the typo

Comment: That looks promising, I will try this and get back too you, thankyou.

Comment: I'm currently getting an error when running the code, in the terminal I am getting Import error: no module named 'urllib3' all my other code seems to work okay still, but when I add streamlit I get this error?

Comment: try installing that package using 'pip install urllib3'. Also have you installed streamlit? If not install it using 'pip install streamlit'

Comment: I must have moved the urllib package folder to the wrong place I just re added it to the right directory and it worked! Thank you for your help, I can really make some progress now

Answer (score 0):

***Is it possible to run python code in a web browser ?*** - Yes, It is now possible with the help of [`PyScript`](https://pyscript.net/). Say thanks to this framework that allows users to create rich Python applications in the browser

There is no installation required. We can just use the PyScript assets served on [`https://pyscript.net/`](https://pyscript.net/)

Live Demo **:**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> <py-script> print('Hello, World!') </py-script> </body>
</html>
```

Note (As per the current official documentation) **:**

> PyScript is very alpha and under heavy development. There are many
> known issues, from usability to loading times, and you should expect
> things to change often. We encourage people to play and explore with
> PyScript, but at this time we do not recommend using it for
> production.